# Define ICompare (Comparator) in Array.Sort Parameter as in (Java)

Tags: c#, icomparer

How can i convert this java style code into C# ? Here is what i have tried already :

I changed the method name from comparable(java) to icompare(c#).

```
Array.Sort(valobject,  new IComparer(){

            public int Compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
                String label1 = ((valobject) obj1).getLabel();
                String label2 = ((valobject) obj2).getLabel();

                if (label1 == null) {
                    if (label2 == null) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (label2 == null) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return (new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(label1, label2 ) ;  
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code conversion service.

Comment: Not really. @MarkusWMahlberg if you just notice you will see the op tried to do it him self.

Comment: it depends on how you look at it. Stackoverflow is a learning platform and as a new C# developer i am trying to learn here. However thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define an implementation of `IComparer` and pass its instance to `Sort` method. There are no anonymous classes in C#.

EDIT:

There is in fact an overload of `Array.Sort` that takes `Comparison` delegate so that it is possible to use lambda function directly:

```
Array.Sort(valobject, (obj1, obj2) => 
{
    String label1 = ((valobject) obj1).getLabel();
    String label2 = ((valobject) obj2).getLabel();
    // ...
    // ...all the rest of the comparison logic
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try to do that, thought there was an easier way like in Java,

Comment: You can create a universal `IComparer` implementation that takes a lambda function in its constructor and then performs comparison with the help of that function. This way you can imitate Java’s anonymous classes behaviour for `IComparer` interface.

Comment: Your answer worth upvote if you put this comment in answer and also with an example ;)

Comment: Oh, there is even a `Sort` overload that takes `Comparison` delegate so no need for special `IComparer` implementation as I supposed in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you. and i hope this can help others in the future. Without the question getting closed for "some" reasons.